# specifying a cell in a sheet in an Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an Excel macro and have a section like the following where I go through a column in a sheet called "the daf" and compare it to a cell in another sheet:

```
For i = 2 To 75
    If Range("the daf!C" + Trim(Str(i))) = Range("scratchpad!Q30") Then
        notes = notes + Range("scratchpad!P30")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The problem is that it produces the result of "#Value!" and the problem appears to be the fact that I have a space in the sheet name because when I replace "the daf" with "scratchpad" it does not produce an error. If what I am saying is correct, then how can I refer to a cell in a sheet when the sheet's name contains a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Sheets("the daf").Range("C" & i)
```

instead of

```
Range("the daf!C" + Trim(Str(i)))
```

Example:

`If Sheets("the daf").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("scratchpad").Range("Q30").Value Then`

**EDIT**

If you still want to use the method that you are using then try this

```
Range("'the" & " " & "daf'!C" & i)
```

Comment: Thanks - it worked! I wonder why it allowed me to use the original way I used? Also, thanks for indicating the "C" & i notation as now I can go over my sheet and simplify the way I have done things.

Comment: Nothing wrong in the way you used originally. It's just that for simplicity sake we do not use that way. However if you see the Edit that I added later on in the post you will notice that you need to pad the spaces. And hence it is more complex than using `Sheets()` method

Comment: Actually, even though I used the sheets method you described, I discovered that my original mistake was not to include single quotes around the sheet name. I.e. it should have been for example: Range("'the daf'!A1")